# Image requested through Ajax in iOS broswer is not shown but it is loaded and in the DOM

Tags: javascript, ios, ajax, debugging, mobile

**Update**

- The size of the image should not be the issue, as rest of the photo
  in my website can still load without any problem.
- I found out that this issue only exists when I browse in iOS.  It
  works perfectly in Android.

I have created an infinite scroll plugin to load more posts through REST API in Wordpress.  The plugin works perfectly on desktop browser, but they cannot load the image in the post when visiting in mobile browser(Tested with Chrome and Safari with my iphoneX).

I have debugged that through remote debug, and this is what I found at the moment.

- The html tag for the image is passed in the XHR response.
- The element of that image is in the DOM.
- No CSS rules like display: none is hiding the image
- The image was received with a status code of 200

What have I missed?

Screenshot for Safari Debugger of the image response:
https://monosnap.com/file/uj4bjX7xGh0YDJR5vO00ALMkDrEPRM

My website: [survivalisthk.com](https://survivalisthk.com) (Scroll to the bottom and then the infinite scroll will start working and fetch those posts that I have problem loading images)

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer for myself right now.  The height of those images were changed to 0px when loaded.  Fixed with the following code:

```
const iOSResize = () => {
    console.log('iOSResize running');
    let img = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
    for( let i = 0; i < img.length; i++){
        img[i].addEventListener('load', function () {
            let naturalH = img[i].naturalHeight;
            let naturalW = img[i].naturalWidth;
            let newH = img[i].width / (naturalW / naturalH);
            console.log(newH);
            img[i].style.height = newH + 'px';
            console.log(img[i].style.height);
        });
    }
};
```

Reference:
[AJAX loaded images not displaying properly in Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45510371/ajax-loaded-images-not-displaying-properly-in-safari)